# cannot eliminate space between 2 horizontal divs inside containing div

Tags: html, css

Should be easy, right?  Just set the outer containing div's padding to zero, and set the two side-by-side divs inside the outer div to have margin:0  but that's having no effect on the space between the 2 horizontal divs.  What I need is the red-outlined left div to touch the green-outlined right-side div.

Despite my effort using padding and margin, the space between the 2 divs will not go away.

I have looked at many answers on SO but so far no one's broken it down to this simple example -- my fiddle shows this issue, at

http://jsfiddle.net/Shomer/tLZrm/7/

And here is the very simple code:

```
<div style="border: 4px solid blue; white-space:nowrap; margin:0; padding:0; width:80%">

   <div style="display:inline-block; width:45%; overflow:hidden; margin:0; border: 1px solid red"> Flimmy-flammy
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block; width:50%; overflow:hidden; margin:0px; border: 1px solid green"> Hambone-Sammy
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="border: 4px solid blue; margin:0; padding:0; width:80%; height: 50px;">

   <div style="float:left; display:inline-block; width:45%; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid red;"> Flimmy-flammy
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; display:inline-block; width:50%; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid green;"> Hambone-Sammy
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I added that to my code -- it works.  I have not used 'float' with 'display:inline-block', didn't know you could do that, I thought you either used one or the other -- lesson learned.  I'm still not sure though why the padding:0 and margin:0 I tried has zero effect.  I added a clear:both div right below and the rest of my code is A-OK -- thank you.

Comment: If you read my comment -- when I looked at your jsfiddle there was just a float in curly braces in a completely different window on the jsfiddle screen.  However Nick put the code *in context* -- I didn't have to guess as to why my code behaved differently.  Again I did up-arrow you.  If want to explain how your float in the curly braces in a separate window of jsfiddle solved my problem let me know -- I still do not see the connection -- what I got from your answer was 'use float' but there was no context I could grasp, sorry I'm new to CSS (3 days only) and new to jsfiddle (1 day only).

Answer (score 22):

The space rendered between your divs is the whitespace (represented as dots), collapsed, in:

```
    </div>.  
.................  
....<div>
```

Instead, try coding like this:

```
    </div><div>
```

and the gap will vanish.

Comment: This is the real explaination for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `float` property.

Example with `div { float: left; }` : http://jsfiddle.net/tLZrm/10/.

Answer (score 5):

The whitespace in the source between inline blocks leads to a gap in the layout. By removing the space (whether it's a single space or some line breaks doesn't matter) the elements will touch as intended.

Formatting of the code can be retained at a slight cost, either by commenting out the whitespace or by making the whitespace occur within tags.

Using comments:

```
<div>
   <div>Content</div><!--
   --><div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Placing linebreak inside tag:

```
<div>
   <div>Content</div
   ><div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @Juan Lanus said in his answer, it is the whitespace causing your issue.

An additional solution is to set `font-size: 0px` on the containing div.

But you will need to then also set `font-size: initial` (or to a non-zero value) on the children div so you can still see your text.