# Unexplainable space above BUTTON inside DIV

Tags: html, css, rendering, html-rendering

Preface: I've read lots of articles about images inside a div having a strange space around them, etc.

Example #1: [Unwanted padding-bottom of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518576/unwanted-padding-bottom-of-a-div)
Example #2: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps
Example #3: [cannot eliminate space between 2 horizontal divs inside containing div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283032/cannot-eliminate-space-between-2-horizontal-divs-inside-containing-div)

Their issues seems similar but not identical to mine. In this sample document, the border, padding, outline, etc are set to zero .. yet both Opera and Firefox render a spare pixel at the top of the div. The third may cheat a way around this space but nobody seems to answer why it's there..

Edit: I read MANY articles that are temptingly close to answering this, but they all seem slightly different with the actual issue.

What am I missing? It's my first question so be patient please :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Anger</title>
    <style>
      *{
        cursor: default;
        margin: 0;
        outline: 0;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      body{
        background-color: #87cefa;
      }
      div{
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }
      button{
        border-radius: 9px;
        padding: 1px 6px 2px 6px;
        font: 14px monospace;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #1e90ff;
      }
    </style>
  <head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button>Sample Button</button>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

Is there some CSS3 that will make it all work? This is an experimental project, so the latest CSS3 is welcomed.

**PS:** I only care about the Opera rendering, though Firefox would be nice to support with the same standards compliant code.. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the line-height on the div to zero.

```
  div{
      background-color: #ffffff;
      line-height:0;
  }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CB8MT/)**

Comment: Thanks! That works, does anyone know where in the specs (I do read them) this behavior is specified?

Comment: Well the line height is related to the font-size which obviously can be different across OSes. You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height and see that the default line-height is about 1.2. Since you didn't specify any font rules in your CSS, the default line height kicked in and resetting it to zero fixed things.

Comment: @Fumbles - CSS 2.1 spec sections [10.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins) and [10.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height). But it's not an easy read.

Comment: @j08691 I'm slightly confused HOW this fix works because the document where I first encountered this issue is completely created via DOM methods.. (thus in theory there should be no spaces in the DOM) We are using the line-height to fix lines that should not exist in my theory. I'll read more specs when I can too.. Thanks for helping get some understanding of what's happening :)

Comment: The vertical-align answer is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Set vertical-align to top on the button. That will fix it.

Comment: aha that works too, is there some "fix" that I can add to my style reset for all elements that will also cure this? If not, then I'll choose between the working answers, and just use it where I notice this issue :)

Comment: I'd argue that this is better since you won't mess up the div's line-height (add another inline element to the div and it will look weird. Why? It's line-height will be 0. You can override though but it's unnecessary work, really). On my reset stylesheet I do believe I have something like button, input, textarea {vertical-align:top; /*among other things*/}. I will develop my answer though to explain why vertical-align top works, and why you need it in the first place. Give me 10 mins.

Comment: Great, I just wish such oddball behaviour was eliminated from specs as it seems to do no good lol